# How do I stop Visual Studio 2022 from automatically changing namespaces and using statements when moving a file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

VisualStudio 2022 v17.2.3 has suddenly started changing the namespaces of my C# files when I drag them to a different directory. In the process it also deletes/adds/modifies using statements (often deleteriously) and updates every file referencing the moved file. It's changing the namespace to the ProjectName.FolderPath.

Searching Tools > Options has turned up nothing. I've disabled all extensions in case one of them was responsible, but it's had no effect. How can this behaviour be stopped?

Comment: But the using directives being added without any reason... how to solve that...

Comment: I'm on VS 17.3.4 and VS still does a terrible job adjusting namespaces. Move a file, it auto changes the namespace in the file and local project files but doesn't change other files in other projects in the same solution that are referencing the file.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To disable this globally, go to

> Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General

and untick the box near the bottom next to ["Enable namespace update when moving files"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8dhW.png). There is a bug in VS2022 that prevents this option being displayed when searched.

Comment: What an absolute horrific feature. Thank you for finding this, was searching all over the place in options.

Comment: I choose **Don't ask again** and **No** and suddenly all namespaces are getting changed... Thanks for this! It doesn't show up in the search...

Comment: I experienced the same as Mikael - despite clicking "Don't ask again" then clicking No, subsequent file moves triggered a rename, as if I had actually answered "Yes". After searching VS settings for the text "namespace", I couldn't find anything remotely matching this feature, so this answer explains why!

Comment: @Kristin horrific?  Under what circumstances would you NOT want the namespaces to change when you move a file to another folder?  I would think they would be very, very seldom.  We've been waiting for this feature for years so we don't have to manually fix up all the namespaces when you move a file.  Given that the default is to prompt you when you first install VS and you can choose "don't prompt me again" with whatever your choice is, I can't see how this could be even easier to accommodate the few people who wouldn't want this behavior.

Comment: @rory.ap Horrific was the wrong word; and was probably fueled by the fact that this feature's necessity doesn't apply to me. That you/your team have been waiting for this for years, doesn't change the fact that the feature changed default behavior. The prompt never came up for me/my team, and the feature was enabled by default upon updating. I wouldn't mind sharing my thoughts as to why I don't need the feature, but the limited length of comments makes it almost impossible, unfortunately. The jest of it: type serialization (yep, disgusting) and namespace != folder structure (yes, contentious).

Comment: @rory.ap I work on absolutely huge, complex projects that require multiple forms of organization. Folders are one tool in that toolbox, and namespaces are another, which are not related. This "feature" is a disaster for those of us who don't have simple requirements.

Comment: Namespaces are logical forms of organization, files/folders etc. are physical. As a norm most developers keep these aligned but that does not mean they should ALWAYS be aligned. VS having set the default for this setting to on is a mistake IMO. Where they are aligned and not aligned is the developer's decision and shouldn't by default be the IDE's.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to disable the namespace update on a per file basis (as opposed to the global setting) then you can add the following directive to the file:

```cs
#pragma warning disable IDE0130 // Namespace does not match folder structure
    
namespace This.Namespace.Stays.Intact
{
    // ...
}
```

From the first glance it disables the warning, but it also disables the namespace update for that file. Which is super handy when you want to exclude that single file from being modified on, say, namespace sync.